# Apache server in Internet and local network, redirection to another ubuntu PC

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I have 2 Ubuntu PCs in my local network

A main server:

```
inet addr:128.125.100.124  Bcast:128.125.100.127  Mask:255.255.255.240
```

which address is public in the Internet and I can get to my website from anywhere ;)

and one another ubuntu PC, which is visible only in my local network

```
inet addr:128.125.100.118  Bcast:128.125.100.127  Mask:255.255.255.240
```

is it possible that this ubuntu PC will be visible using my Internet opened ubuntu server 128.125.100.124? For example that I redirect some sub-domain access to this PC 128.125.100.118

Answer (score 0):

IP address 128.125.100.124 is registered to the University of Southern California (reported by command `whois 128.125.100.124`). You will need to talk to the university network administrators and ask them whether they will allow you to run servers on any of these addresses.

I tried accessing that IP address from here but nothing happened. I am not sure whether you can get to your site from anywhere in the world.

If you were hoping to use 128.125.100.124 as some kind of a router that can forward packets to 128.125.100.118 you are out of luck - this is not going to happen. Routing and firewalls are handled by your network admins.